# How do I convert OpenCV to PIL with RGBA format in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library, webcam

I want to convert a webcam shot in OpenCV to PIL so I can read the image pixel for pixel and get the RGB format.

I usually get the RGBA format when working with PIL, but now I get one integer instead of the four numbers I was expecting.

Consider this code snippet:

```
cv.SetCaptureProperty(capture, cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, my_height)
cv.SetCaptureProperty(capture, cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, my_width)
cv.SetCaptureProperty(capture, cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FORMAT, cv.IPL_DEPTH_32F)
  img = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
...
    index_value = index_value + 1
    picture_time = current_time + variance
    #Give the cv image to PIL
    im = Image.fromstring("L", cv.GetSize(img), img.tostring())
    #Get the color set out of the images
    width, height = im.size
    image_pixels = im.load()
    total_size = width * height
    colors = {}
    for h in range(height):
        for w in range(width):
            print width, height
            detail = image_pixels[w, h]
            #Filter our transparencies and dark colors
            print detail
```

I get a value of things like 14 when I cover the webcam and 140 when I don't.

How do I properly grab an image from the webcam in a Pythonic way and get the RGB value of each pixel?

Comment: What pixel format are `cv.QueryFrame` + `img.tostring()` returning image data to you in? The `"L"` mode argument you're passing to `Image.fromstring()` is telling it to expect 8-bit black and white pixels.

Comment: @martineau, I've been looking for that information so I could help answer this question, but it doesn't seem to be documented *anywhere*.

Comment: Why are you using old `cv` instead of `cv2`?

Comment: @MarkRansom: I had the same problem finding out. If all else fails, perhaps the OP could determine it experimentally by examining the contents of what is being returned after frame-grabbing different solidly colored sheets of paper (ideally Red, Green, & Blue).

Comment: I decided to try saving the image after I did the conversion.  Sure enough, it's grascale. Yes, there is little documentation on what the "L" is.

Comment: I changes the "L" to "RGB" and I got a blue image.  I suppose that would count as closer.

Comment: I tried with another camera and instead of a blue shirt, which I have one, I got an orange shirt.

Comment: Related to this question is the list of modes.  That is, the "L". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199522/list-of-image-modes